# How to use power shell to exctract values from command output

Tags: windows, powershell, monitoring, raid

I'm trying to get Adaptec raid array status by using `arcconf` cli and `power shell` for monitoring.
Can not figure out the way to get the last values from the command returned string in power shell.

```
PS C:\adaptec\msm\cmdline> .\arcconf.exe  getconfig  1  | select-string   -pattern "Defunct disk drive count"

   Defunct disk drive count                 : 0
```

I need to get the  `0` value  from command output.

Answer (score 0):

split the result at the caracter ':' and take the second part. Something like

```
((.\arcconf.exe getconfig 1 | select-string -pattern "Defunct disk drive count") -split ':')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(.\arcconf.exe getconfig 1) -match 'defunct disk drive count\s+:\s+(\d+)'
$matches[1]
```